# Both WP_Query and get_posts returning 1 post

Tags: wp-query, loop, get-posts

I am having a weird issue. Both `WP_Query` and `get_posts` returning only one result, i.e only the latest post. Never faced this before..

The `WP_Query`:

```
function custom_tsr_query() {

    $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'posts_per_page' => 10 )); ?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>      
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>       
    <?php else : ?>

        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

    <?php endif;
}
```

And, the `get_posts`:

```
function custom_tsr_query2() {
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
    );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
    <?php 
        endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

I really can't see any fault with any of these two codes. What could possibly be causing them to output only a single result?

Checked all the possible similar questions here in SE, but none of them worked.

Comment: The only problem I see is in the second function, `orderby` should be by `date`, not `post_date`. Is this function hooked somewhere. Have you tested this on a clean install with a defaults theme. Are you getting debug errors. Look at your generated SQL query (`echo $the_query->request`)

Comment: Yes, its a clean install using twentyfourteen theme. Here is the result of the generated SQL query.. `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10`. No debug errors though.

Comment: TBH, I'm stumped. If: a.) You don't have syntax errors b.) Have a clean install with a bundled theme c.) No custom filters d.) Haven't hooked the function to a incorrect hook and e.) Have a correctly generated SQL query, then I'm at a loss. As a last resort, verify your posts and check everything in your `wp_posts` table and make sure your posts are saved as the are expected to be